# Get terms cross-taxonomy query

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm creating a product list with two custom taxonomies: the producer and the category. I've managed to display all of the producers and make the products display in a collapsible tab accordingly, but I want to exclude from display those producers, who don't have any products in the currently displayed category. 
The 'display all producers' code looks like this:

```
$terms = get_terms("producers");
if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                    $i=1;
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    <div>producer's name, etc.</div>
                    }
                }
```

How do I exclude producers that don't have any products assigned in the CURRENT category? 'hide_empty' argument doesn't work, as they have products in other categories.

Edit: to be more clear, the category itself is shown basing on the current post, '/categories/trucks/' will show only trucks (but still all of producers, even those who do not have any trucks assigned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, few hours of figuring it out, but I made it:
I had to wrap the whole thing into a wp_query, querying the current 'category' term and then use get_the_terms instead of get_terms to get the terms for the current post query, then remove duplicates and echo it in a foreach loop similar to the initial one.